# async/await functions in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Assume I have an LWC component and Apex Aura controller:

```java
/* AccountController.cls */
public with sharing class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAll() {
        try {
            /* some foo logic */
            return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!--cmp.html --->
<template>
    <template if:false={isLoaded}>
        <lightning-spinner variant="brand" alternative-text="Loading..."></lightning-spinner>
    </template>
</template>
```

```js
/* cmp.js */
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAll from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAll';

export default class Cmp extends LightningElement {

    @track isLoaded = false;
    @track accounts;
    @track error;

    connectedCallback() {
        getAll()
            .then(result => {
                console.log('1st then');
                this.accounts = result;
                /* or any other function that returns promise */
                return this.promiseFunc();
            })
            .then(value => {
                console.log('2nd then executes after 3 seconds , value: ' + value);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.isLoaded = true;
            });
    }

    promiseFunc() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('foo');
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
}
```

This example works perfectly, but when tried to rewrite promises into async/await:

```js
/* cmp.js */
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAll from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAll';

export default class Cmp extends LightningElement {

    @track isLoaded = false;
    @track accounts;
    @track error;

    connectedCallback() {
        var result = await getAll();
        this.accounts = result;
        var value = await this.promiseFunc();
        console.log('returned after 3s , value: ' + value);
        this.isLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

It throws Error

> Error:(35, 15) LWC1503: Parsing error: await is a reserved word
>   (35:15)

But if both `getAll()` and `this.promiseFunc()` returns promises, why can't I await them?
Is `async/await` syntax is allowed for Lightning Web Components?
If yes then how to rewrite promises into `async/await` correctly and how to catch possible errors?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`async/await` syntax is fully supported by LWC. However, as it was introduced in ES8,  in old browsers, this syntax is transpiled down to ES5, which can cause performance issues if the code is executed many times.

> the `await` keyword is only valid inside `async` functions

In your case to make your code deployable with using `async/await syntax` you can use 3 approaches:

1. Declare some `async init()` function and invoke it within `connectedCallback()` hook:

```js
connectedCallback() {
    this.init();
}


async init() {
    try {
        this.accounts = await getAll();
        const value = await this.promiseFunc();
        console.log('2nd then executes after 3 seconds async, value:' + value);
    } catch (error) {
        this.error = error;
    } finally {
        this.isLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

2. Invoke it anonymously as an `IIFE`:

```js
connectedCallback() {
    (async () => {
        try {
            this.accounts = await getAll();
            const value = await this.promiseFunc();
            console.log('2nd then executes after 3 seconds async, value:' + value);
        } catch (error) {
            this.error = error;
        } finally {
            this.isLoaded = true;
        }
    })();
}
```

3. Make your `connectedCallback()` lifecycle hook `async`:

```js
async connectedCallback() {
    try {
        this.accounts = await getAll();
        await this.errorPromise();
        const value = await this.promiseFunc();
        console.log('2nd then executes after 3 seconds async, value:' + value);
    } catch (error) {
        this.error = error;
    } finally {
        this.isLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend you to use the 3rd option at least for API consistency. Not sure about long term effects.

As for catching errors of async functions you can use `try/catch` block or handle them separately, using `catch()` method because async function implicitly returns a promise:

```js
this.accounts = await getAll().catch(error => this.error = error);
const value = await this.promiseFunc().catch((/*rejected obj*/) => /*error handling*/);
```

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: The [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) uses the third option on the example, so i guess it's API proof

Comment: Could you please confirm if I can pass a parameter to getAll method?

Comment: It depends on the apex controller method signature

Answer (score 8):

I see that problem is resolved, but I would like to share my thoughts about it. Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Main assumption:

- The async function returns a promise
- Await is used for calling an async function and waits for resolve/reject
- **Use await if operation B is dependent on operation A**
- Async/await is an excellent option if you find yourself writing long, complicated waterfalls of .then statements

Code:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getTextMethod1 from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getTextMethod1';
import getTextMethod2 from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getTextMethod2';
import getTextMethod3 from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getTextMethod3';

export default class LwcPromise extends LightningElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        this.invokeApexMethods();
    }
 
    async invokeApexMethods() {
        try {
            const result1 = await getTextMethod1();
            console.log('Method1 result: ' + result1);
            const result2 = await getTextMethod2({
                message1: result1
            });
            console.log('Method2 result: ' + result2);
            const result3 = await getTextMethod3({
                message2: result2
            });
            console.log('Method3 result: ' + result3);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } finally {
            console.log('Finally Block');
        }
    }
}
```

More information here: https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/promises-in-lwc-lightning-web-components