# How to use Promises / synchronize two asynchronous methods in Lightning Web Component(LWC)?

Tags: api, lightning-web-components, callout, asynchronous, promises

In LWC JS, I am making an external API call-out and an Apex method and accumulating the results. How to synchronizes the process?

Example:

```
renderedCallback(){
  let a,b;
  getApiResult().then(result => {
      this.a = result;
   })
  apexMethod().then(result=>{
      this.b = this.a + result;
  })
  console.log(a+b);
}
```

How can get the value of a into the apexMethod? And also consider the logging result at the end.

Answer (score 4):

You can go by what Rahul has suggested, its called as Promise chaining.

Modern javascript has new concepts that allow you to handle these complex requirements without making you go in promise chaining callback hell.

Welcome Async and Await :)

> await - > The keyword await makes JavaScript wait until that promise
>   settles and returns its result.
>
> async - > The word “async” before a function means one simple thing: a
>   function always returns a promise. Other values are wrapped in a
>   resolved promise automatically.

So your code will be something like:

```
async function doComplexCallout() {
    let responseFromApi1 = await fetch('https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/');
    let responseFromApi2 = await doApexCall(responseFromApi1.data); //sending response of first call to second.

}
```

Async and await are completely supported by lwc and modern browser as mentioned here 
[async/await functions in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278655/async-await-functions-in-lwc)

src: https://javascript.info/async-await

Regarding logging: You can put the code of async function inside the try-catch block and log whenever error happens and promise is not resolved.

Src: https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a

Answer (score 3):

The first thing, be sure that you want to perform this in `renderedCallback`, because it runs very frequent. This runs every time your component is rendered on events like `@track, @api, @wire` are properties updated.

to make successive promises you can do like this.

```
renderedCallback() {
    let a, b;
    getApiResult().then(result => {
        this.a = result;
        apexMethod().then(result => {
            this.b = this.a + result;
            console.log(a + b);
        })
    })
}
```