# Chaining async apex calls in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

In my LWC Component, I want to chain my apex callouts. Meaning, first ApexCall 1 should happen then apex Call 2 should happen and so on. So, for that, I am using JS Promises chaining method like below:

```
chainApexCalls(){

    doApexCalls({
            ..
        })
            .then(() => {
                alert('Call Apex 1');
                this.apex1();
            })
            .then(() => {
                alert('Call Apex 2');
                this.apex2();
            })
            .then(()=>{
                alert('Call Apex 3');
                this.apex3();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                
            });

}


apex1(){
    doApex1Callout({
            ..
        })
        .then(() => {
                alert('Apex Call 1 finished');
            })
}

apex2(){
    doApex2Callout({
            ..
        })
        .then(() => {
                alert('Apex Call 2 finished');
            })
}
```

In this, as soon as the `alert('Call Apex 1');` is called, I am expecting next alert to be `alert('Apex Call 1 finished');` but the issue is that the `alert('Call Apex 2')` is called first and then `alert('Apex Call 1 finished');` is called.

Is there any way that I can chain these async Apex calls?

Expected Output should be : `1. alert('Call Apex 1');` `2.  alert('Apex Call 1 finished');` `3.  alert('Call Apex 2');` `4.  alert('Apex Call 2 finished');` `5.  alert('Call Apex 3');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

then block only ensures `this.apex1();` , `this.apex2();`, `this.apex3();` that the method is called in order. But there is no order when it gets executed.

apex1() contains an async method. the async method will execute independently.hence you are getting the behavior.

Have a look at https://javascript.info/async-await

[async/await functions in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278655/async-await-functions-in-lwc)

Comment: Okay, so you're saying if I use await for this.apex1,this.apex2,this.apex3 then it will be sequential?

Comment: Yes.. IT will wait till first method finishes execution

Comment: Wow.. It is working as expected now.. This is Awesome.. Thank you so much..!!