# Unexpected compilation error: Cannot read property 'type' of null

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to use async /await in an LWC component as stated [THIS LINK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278655/async-await-functions-in-lwc)

But while deploying my code i am getting **LWC1001: Unexpected compilation error:**  ***Cannot read property 'type' of null***

I have done both the ways
1)Declare some async init() function and invoke it within connectedCallback() hook:
2)Invoke it anonymously as an IIFE:

**APEX**

```
public class myAsyncAwaitController(){ 
 @AuraEnabled
    public static Integer methodName1(){
        try {
            return 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Integer methodName4(Integer i){
        try {
            return 5+i;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

1. Declare some async init() function and invoke it within connectedCallback() hook:

   ```
    import { LightningElement} from 'lwc';
    import methodName1 from '@salesforce/apex/myAsyncAwaitController.methodName1';
    import methodName4 from '@salesforce/apex/myAsyncAwaitController.methodName2';

    export default class AsycAwaitLWC extends LightningElement {
        connectedCallback(){  
           this.initfunc();
        }
        async initfunc(){
            try{
                console.log('Async Called Invoked');
                let result1 =  await methodName1();
                let result2 =  await methodName4(result1);
                let finalResult = result1+result2; 
                console.log('finalResult',finalResult);
            }
            catch{
                console.log('Inside Catch');
            }
            finally{
                console.log('Finally !!!');
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Option 2 : As an IIFE

```
import { LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import methodName1 from '@salesforce/apex/myAsyncAwaitController.methodName1';
import methodName4 from '@salesforce/apex/myAsyncAwaitController.methodName2';


export default class AsycAwaitLWC extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){  
      (async()=>{
        try{
            console.log('Async Called Invoked');
            let result1 =  await methodName1();
            let result2 =  await methodName4(result1);
            let finalResult = result1+result2; 
            console.log('finalResult',finalResult);
        }
        catch{
            console.log('Inside Catch');
        }
        finally{
            console.log('Finally !!!');
        }
      })()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import methodName4 from '@salesforce/apex/myAsyncAwaitController.methodName2';
```

Should apparently be:

```
import methodName4 from '@salesforce/apex/myAsyncAwaitController.methodName4';
```

I'm not sure why you're getting such an odd error method, but this is the only thing I can see that stands out immediately.

Either calling approach should work.

Comment: Oh yes that was the typo.. but its not working even for my manager , wondering if it is some VS code config issue , but i am not sure

Comment: @SwarandeepSingh What does "not working" mean? That's not very descriptive.

Comment: I mean he is also getting same error  and unable to deploy

Answer (score 1):

Please correct the imports as per @sfdcfox.

Also, make sure to correct catch block as "catch(error)". Please refer to below code:

```
    export default class AsycAwaitLWC extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){  
        this.initfunc();
     }
     async initfunc(){
         try{
             console.log('Async Called Invoked');
             let result1 =  await methodName1();
             let result2 =  await methodName4(result1);
             let finalResult = result1+result2; 
             console.log('finalResult',finalResult);
         }
         catch(error){
             console.log('Inside Catch');
         }
         finally{
             console.log('Finally !!!');
         }
     }
}
```

Hope this resolves your issue.