# How to handle a Javascript event inside .then method of a Promise ? LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Hello everyone and thanks for reading:

I´m having a problem in a Javascript file from a LWC I´ve built.

```
handleSaveUniqueRecord (event)
{
    //clone event obj using spread
    //event cant be used inside .then because of different scope
    this.eventClone = event;
    let objField = [];

    console.log('tst access reference1 ' + this.eventClone.target.name);
    console.log('tst access reference2 ' + event.target.name);


    saveUniqueFieldData ({fieldRecordId: event.target.dataset.id,
        fieldRecordValue: event.target.value.toString(),
        fieldAnswerLabel: event.target.dataset.selectedanswerlabel,
        fieldRecordNodeType: event.target.dataset.nodetype,
        fieldStatus: event.target.dataset.status != null ? event.target.dataset.status : event.target.value.toString() === '' ? 'Incomplete': 'Complete',
        sectionId: this.formDataArray.salesforceValueId,
        sectionStatus:  this.formDataArray.status
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log('result inside promise   ', result)

        //when changing the value that disables the dependant field the value of the dependant field needs to be cleared 
        //pending development
        console.log('tst access reference eventClone inside THEN ' + this.eventClone.target.name);
        console.log('tst access reference event inside THEN ' + this.event.target.name);
        this.error = false;

        console.log('loguea despues del name ??')

        //Update section status and send it back to parent component
        this.formDataArray.status = result;
    })
    .catch(error => {

        console.log('error in DynamicFormFields.js' );
        //show toast error message when something went wrong with saving the individual question.
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error saving form data',
                message: error.message ,
                variant: 'error',
                mode:'sticky'
            })
        );
        this.error = true;
    });

    //needs to be changed to then promise
    if (this.error == true)
    {
        objField = this.formDataArray.fieldsBlock.find(t=>t.internalId===event.target.name);
        console.log(' .... inside error if ... ', event.target.name)
        //update the original value in the JSON for future validations
        objField.value = objField.originalValue;
        objField.errorSaving = true;
    }
    else{
        console.log('function init');
        let objField = [];
        objField = this.formDataArray.fieldsBlock.find(t=>t.internalId===event.target.name);

        console.log('after objfield ' + objField);
        console.log('after objfield ' + objField.nodeType);
        //update the original value in the JSON for future validations
        if (objField.nodeType!= "InputTextArea")
            this.formDataArray.rating = (+this.formDataArray.rating - (+objField.originalValue) ) + event.target.value ;

        objField.originalValue = event.target.value;
        
        objField.errorSaving = false;
        objField.valueChanged = false;

        this.updateSectionValues ();
    }
}
```

This is the code.

It recieves an event and calls the saveUniqueFieldData Apex method which returns a String ('Incompleted' in my case) and then needs to do something in the .then function of the promise.
Inside the .then method I need to get the value of this lines

```
  console.log('tst access reference eventClone inside THEN ' + this.eventClone.target.name);
  console.log('tst access reference event inside THEN ' + this.event.target.name);
```

but they are both comming back as '*undefined*' and I can't understand why they are working fine before the .then method

```
console.log('tst access reference1 ' + this.eventClone.target.name);
    console.log('tst access reference2 ' + event.target.name);
```

and not inside it.

Comment: I imagine an exception is being thrown. But then I would expect you to see the details in the console, unless something is catching and silently ignoring the exception...

Comment: Hi @PhilW, thanks for the comment. I've updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `event` DOM property is not directly accessible when promise is resolved i.e. inside `.then`.

You need to create a local property [named `target` in this example] to hold `event.target`, doing so `target` is accessible inside `.then`-

```js
handleSaveUniqueRecord (event) {
    let target = event.target;

    saveUniqueFieldData ({
        // your properties here
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log('access reference event inside THEN ' + target.name);
    }
}
```

Psuedo working example on [https://webcomponents.dev/](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/6lCtHzCzJkGQCyzLRplw)

OR Another alternative would be to use [`async/await`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278655/async-await-functions-in-lwc) pattern.

Note: I think `event` represent DOM which is accessible in sync call inside a function, when you call a promise; its executed in a separate microtask where DOM is not accessible anymore.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Raul ! I´ll check it out and let you know :)

Comment: Raul, thanks for the answer !!! It´s a bit odd how your solution works but mine, cloning the hole event and then using it as a class variable won't. I can't see why, but it worked. Thanks :D