# calling method in connectedcallback not working as expected

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to set orderId before I call displayOrderProducts(). Even though I'm calling the method to set orderId before the method it is used in, it seems to reverse the order:

console:

```
orderId-------2------- undefined
orderId-----1--------- a093S000001QjyyQAC
```

.js:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import orderProducts from '@salesforce/apex/ResourceListController.orderProducts';
import getOrder from '@salesforce/apex/ResourceListController.getOrder';

export default class ResourceAssignForListPage extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    orderId;
    @track orderProductsList;
    @track objectApiName = 'Order_Product__c';

    setOrderId() {

        getOrder({recordId: this.recordId})
        .then(data => {
            this.orderId = data.Id;
            console.log('orderId-----1---------',this.orderId);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });


    }

    displayOrderProducts() {
        this.orderProductsList = [];

        console.log('orderId-------2-------',this.orderId);
        orderProducts({recordId: this.orderId})
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(record => {
                this.orderProductsList.push(record);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        this.setOrderId();
        this.displayOrderProducts();
    }
}
```

I would expect the console.logs to be in opposite order. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would take a look at this answer, as it seems to cover the same territory?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278655/async-await-functions-in-lwc

Comment: I haven't had success implementing the suggestions from the above thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make a call to the server, the code continues running without waiting for the response from the server. The `then` is guaranteed, in this case, to be called after `displayOrderProducts`. The solution is to wait for the response from the server. You can write this with more promises, but I find it easier to just use async/await:

```
async setOrderId() {
  try {
    const order = await getOrder({recordId: this.recordId});
    this.orderId = order.Id;
  } catch(e) {
    // Handle server error here
  }
}
async connectedCallback() {
  await this.setOrderId();
  this.displayOrderProducts();
}
```

For completeness, using Promises would look like this:

```
  setOrderId() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      getOrder({ recordId: this.recordId })
        .then((data) => {
          this.orderId = data.Id;
          console.log("orderId-----1---------", this.orderId);
          resolve();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }

  displayOrderProducts() {
    this.orderProductsList = [];
    console.log("orderId-------2-------", this.orderId);
    orderProducts({ recordId: this.orderId })
      .then((data) => {
        data.forEach((record) => {
          this.orderProductsList.push(record);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.setOrderId().then(() => {
      this.displayOrderProducts();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Another solution that I arrived at is to move this.displayOrderProducts(); to inside setOrderId(), after console.log("orderId-----1---------", this.orderId);
Which I think does the same thing. Thanks @sfdcfox!